# Can UPS be dangerous for my pc?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer, ups

Can UPS be dangerous for my pc?
I am using this power supply in my pc: *SilentiumPC Supremo FM2 750W 80 Plus Gold*
I am using this UPS to power my pc and monitor: *Green Cell UPS (2000VA/1400W, 3x IEC, 2x Schuko, AVR, LCD)*

I am totally green when it comes to watts, volts, amps, etc. and I have started wondering if this UPS can be dangerous for my pc. My main concern is that when I looked on the LCD display it says that there is 225V on input and output. I doubt that 225V is really going in to my PC+monitor but wanted to make sure because this seems like a really high voltage.

PC and monitor are directly connected to UPS and UPS is directly connected to power outlet

Comment: What country do you live in?

Comment: @gronostaj Poland

Comment: In short, no there's nothing to be concerned about _(see [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law))_. Electrical devices only use as much electricity as they require and almost all electrical devices use DC, not AC, which is why the power supplies for electronics are relatively large, whether it's the power adapter itself or PSU. The UPS has a total discharge capacity of 2000VA for AC and 1400W for DC [`V*A=W` | AC uses RMS values] _(see [Electronic Design](https://www.electronicdesign.com/markets/energy/article/21801657/whats-the-difference-between-watts-and-voltamperes))_

Comment: @JW0914 It's a reasonable question though, since OP is concerned about voltage. Current is "pulled" by devices and they never get more than they want, but voltage is "pushed" by the source - if the source is 225V, all devices get 225V no matter for what voltage they are designed to operate on. "Devices use as much electricity as they require" is only true if the voltage is right.

Comment: @gronostaj True, but electronics don't use AC, nor will most UPS' allows more than a specific percentage above and below it's rated output [under-volt/over-volt] to get pushed before cutting off the voltage supply to those circuits, as most, if not all, UPS' are surge protectors. Should more voltage get pushed to a device that's incapable of processing it, at worst the PSU/power adapter would get fried, as you don't get voltage without current or current without voltage _(voltage is the pressure, current is the amount)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the world, including Poland, runs on 220-240V mains voltage. Here's a [map from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#/media/File:World_Map_of_Mains_Voltages_and_Frequencies,_Detailed.svg) showing mains voltages across the world. Shades of blue and green are in the 220-240V range.

[image: Voltage map as of January 2021]

For Poland specifically, the voltage should ideally be 230V, although some variations and measurement errors are to be expected. Everything that's connected to a wall at your house works at ~230V AC.

Electronic devices will internally convert power to lower voltage DC. For example laptop power supplies produce 12-19V DC and USB chargers use 5V, with some supporting 9V, 15V and 20V for fast charging. A standard internal PC power supply produces 12V, 5V and 3.3V, because different components have different voltage requirements.